# How can i use Filter Expression in jmx logger LogConsole?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, monitoring

I am using JMX Logger for monitoring java web application.MBean Server connect successfully and i see logs in JMX logger LoggerConsole but i dont know how to use Filter Expression in loggerconsole.
this is my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="jmxlogger" class="jmxlogger.integration.log4j.JmxLogAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <param name="ObjectName" value="jmxlogger:type=LogEmitter"/>
    <param name="MBeanServer" value="platform"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value ="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="jmxlogger" />
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

[image]

now my question is i want to filter trough raw data for example **I am happy only** what i will do?
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wiki <sup>**1**</sup> of [JmxLogger](https://code.google.com/p/jmx-logger/), you need the parameter `FilterExpression`. The expression use [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Home) and the [**`contains`**](http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Operators) operator can be useful.  Then your `appender` would be as follows:

```xml
<appender name="jmxlogger" class="jmxlogger.integration.log4j.JmxLogAppender">
    <param name="FilterExpression" value="rawMessage contains 'I am happy!'"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <param name="ObjectName" value="jmxlogger:type=LogEmitter"/>
    <param name="MBeanServer" value="platform"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

---

*Notes*

1. *A quick guide on how to use JmxLogger*, https://code.google.com/p/jmx-logger/wiki/JmxLoggerUsage

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But in my application so many logs are there like transaction logs,exception logs, error logs etc.that time i need to search different raw data at run time what i will do?please help me.

Comment: Use the operator `||` e.g. `rawMessage contains 'I am happy!' || rawMessage contains 'something wrong' || exceptionName contains 'JDBCException'`

Comment: we don't know right in our entire application having different data logs means lakh of logs are there that time what i will do? if i need to filter particular logs after getting error or exception  in application at run time.

Comment: In that case, the [Find command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_%28command%29) will be more faster.

Comment: When i userd **||** in xml file its gives an exception.i.e **log4j:WARN Failed to set property [filterExpression] to value "rawMessage contains 'I am happy!' || rawMessage contains 'something wrong' || exceptionName contains 'JDBCException'". 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**